# p:ajaxStatus how to show notification message after saving record

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a save button which calls a method in my backing Bean. When it's clicked, I'd like to show notification message, and for that I went for Primefaces' ajaxStatus. . Here's the code of the button (p:commandButton):

```
<p:commandButton value="OK"
    action="#{myBean.saveRecord}" />
```

and the ajaxStatus outside it:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();"
            onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />
        <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog"
            header="Success operation" draggable="false"
            closable="false" resizable="false" style="text-align: center">
        </p:dialog>
```

thank you for your help

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: how to create generic notification message for all xhtml page not to use growl and message component, i would to use same principe of statusAjax.

Comment: Use an includ and add in every page this AjaxStuts what do you think about it

Answer (score 1):

Add on your saveRecord method at the end:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('statusDialog').show();");
```

Comment: But by this instruction ManagedBean control xhtml !

Comment: OK, so you can put it on your xhtml p:commandButton => onComplete="PF('statusDialog').show();"

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an ajaxStatus on your page, the javascript that you've putted on the onstart & onsuccess events will be triggered and you already now that, right ?!

On these scripts you can use the widgetVar directly because PrimeFaces create javascript variables on the global (window) scope with the names you informed:

```
onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"
```

If you want to reuse this solution on others pages just put it on a template file and enjoy :)

Sorry if i have misunderstood your problem.

Cheers